# Do different browsers offer different set of Web APIs?

Tags: web, browser, web-standards

As per this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API, there are a set of Web APIs which are the standard APIs as per w3c definition. However, I could not find information regarding the set of APIs that are actually offered by different browsers?

- Are all browser vendors supposed to implement all of these APIs?
- Can browser vendors offer custom APIs not standardized by w3c ( and probably not provided by other browsers)
- Orthogonal, but are API specifications a part of the underlying HTML version specification, for example are all the current Web APIs standardized by w3c a part of HTML5?